# Something like _spPageContextInfo, but for publishing pages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, publishing-page, managed-navigation

We are using managed navigation for our site collection and subsites and I need to get some info about the pages I'm on using javascript.

I'm familiar with using using `executeQueryAsync()` in JSOM to send requests for information from the termstore and all, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm used to using **_spPageContextInfo** to get various useful bits of information about the current page and site. I often just type this into the console to refer to things and check some details that I need to confirm.

I seem to remember that there is some object that is available on every page something like that has words like **friendly** or **segment** or something like that in it. I've tried many combinations and search the code, but I'm not finding it. Searching google points out all kinds of things about setting up the navigation and JSOM/REST examples.

Does anybody know about a javascript object/variable that is automatically loaded onto every publishing/managed navigation page and is similar to _spPageContextInfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be **_spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo**. Oddly it is undefined on several of my friendly url pages and defined on others. So I have no idea what is going on with that.

It returns the following properties

- termId
- termSetId
- termStoreId
- title (not sure which title, but I'm guessing the label for the term)

Answer (score 0):

Publishing page contains this `_spPageContextInfo` also, just make sure the script init complete.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(cunstomLogic, "sp.js");
        function cunstomLogic() {
            console.log(_spPageContextInfo);
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I know _spPageContextInfo. There is something else that I remember finding before that is similar, but offers different information.